# Disabling Mouse Wheel for X Milliseconds with javascript?

Tags: javascript, freeze, mousewheel, milliseconds

I have a Website with RoyalSlider and Mousewheel support. http://www.linus.de/mark/drei.php

Everything works fine, but when i use my macbook (touchpad) the thing is that i fire several mousewheel events at a time when scrolling. so basically i want the script to pause for the time (or a bit less) it takes for one slide to change...

What i would need is a javascript which freezes the mousewheel for x milliseconds each time it's been triggered (after sending 1 or -1 to the slider)...

Answer (score 2):

A Timer with a call back and a flag could work. When you start to scroll you set the flag and not allow the scroll wheel to function, see [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) on how to disable the scroll wheel. When the timer fires (1 second or so) you reset the flag to let the person scroll again. See [This page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)  for how to set up a timer with a call back

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a full code example since you didn't give any code to us but here's the solution.
When you scroll the mouse, a scroll animation begins. Create a variable somewhere outside the event handler, let's say

```
var animationInProgress = false;
```

and set it to `true` **right before** the animation begining. Then, this RoyalSlider plugin must have some kind of `complete` handler (I bet it has - it's paid though) - a parameter where you can put a function to be called when the animation is over. So, you put there a function similar to that:

```
function() {
    animationInProgress = false;
}
```

The last thing is to check the value of the `animationInProgress` variable each time you want to run an animation

```
if (false === animationInProgress) {
    //run the animation
}
```

I hope you get the idea.